# Getting 2 buttons with a datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

So i'm currently working on a datepicker which already has a calendar button which brings up the calendar for selecting a date. The button at the bottom that says "Today" works and sends the correct date into the input. However, I am required to create a second button next to the calendar icon that does that exact same thing. 
I want it to look something like this:

[image]

Just wanted to see if it's possible for the datepicker to have multiple triggers. The code behind the today button is done and tested and working, i just need to be able to create this button everytime there is a datepicker. Since the datepicker is used in over 100 different places within the project, it is not really ideal to go into each of these files and add a new button just for this. If possible i'd like to create this button when the datepicker is initialized.

Comment: I cannot connect the question to the problem you cited at the end, I do not understand how those two are connected. The answer to the question however is that, yes, it is possible. Also, why would you need to to edit the datepicker in every file that uses it? Hopefully, the datepicker has its own files that are used across the entire project. You make it seem like you hardcoded the datepicker into the UI, which is very hard to maintain.

Comment: No we have our own Date class, which initializes the datepicker. It uses datepicker whenever this date class is used to initialize the input. The datepicker is not hardcoded into the UI. Setting up the datepicker is in one place. However I can not figure out how to add an extra button next to the calendar as shown above. As for the last line, maybe my wording is off, but it is connected because it should create a button next to the input every time the date field is used.